# Is there a surjective homomorphism $\mu _{16}\rightarrow U(15)$?

Tags: group-theory

Is there a surjective homomorphism $\mu _{16}\rightarrow U(15)$?

The image has to be all of $U(15)$, if the homomorphism is to be surjective. Would this be correct? $\varphi _{k}(a)=k$ where $a\in \mu _{16}$ and $a=e^{\frac{\pi ik}{8}}$. Thus, the image would be all of $U(15)$, right? I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

$\mu _{16}$ is 16-roots of unity and U(15) is multiplication group mod 15 U(15) = {1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14}

Comment: What is $\mu_n$?

Comment: @AlexProvost : I think this is the $n$th-roots of unity but what is $U(15)$ ?

Comment: @N.H. The group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/15$, presumably.

Comment: @AlexProvost : yes, it's n-th roots of unity and U(15) is multiplication group mod 15 {1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14}

Comment: @JMK You should include this in your question to make it as self-contained and understandable as possible.

Comment: @AlexProvost : Ok, for me $U(n)$ is the group of unitary $n \times n$ matrix, hence my confusion...

Answer (score 1):

We have $\mu(16) \cong \mathbb Z/16 \mathbb Z$.

On the other hand, $U(15)$ is not cyclic. So such morphism does not exists, as the image of a cyclic group is cyclic.